# (Inverse-) Sorting 2d numpy array column-wise

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

The following code sorts an 2d numpy array column-wise forth and back

```
import numpy as np
#Column-wise sort and inverse sort of image (2d array)
nrows = 10
ncols = 5
a = np.random.randint(nrows, size=(nrows, ncols))
a_sorted = np.sort(a, axis=0)

ori_indices = np.zeros_like(a)
for c in range(ncols):
    ori_indices[:,c] = np.argsort(np.argsort(a[:,c]))
#Do some work on sorted array, like e.g row-wise filtering
#After processing sorted array, move it back to original order
a_backsorted = np.zeros_like(a)
for c in range(ncols):
    a_backsorted[:,c] = a_sorted[:,c][ori_indices[:,c]]

print (a); print ()
print (a_backsorted); print ()
print (a_sorted); print ()
```

The code work as is but I guess there is a more efficient implementation without for loop (using fancy indexing)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `a_sorted[::-1]` to reverse the array

```
print (a_sorted); print ()
print (a_sorted[::-1])

[[0 0 0 2 0]
 [2 0 0 2 2]
 [4 0 2 6 4]
 [4 2 3 7 5]
 [4 4 4 7 6]
 [5 5 4 8 7]
 [6 5 4 8 7]
 [7 6 8 9 8]
 [8 7 9 9 9]
 [8 8 9 9 9]]

[[8 8 9 9 9]
 [8 7 9 9 9]
 [7 6 8 9 8]
 [6 5 4 8 7]
 [5 5 4 8 7]
 [4 4 4 7 6]
 [4 2 3 7 5]
 [4 0 2 6 4]
 [2 0 0 2 2]
 [0 0 0 2 0]]
```

Comment: I should clarify myself: It is not about reverting the ordering (ascending/descending), it is about how to invert the sort operation (after the sorted array was modified) i.e how to invert the permutation applied to each column.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Column-wise sort and inverse sort of image (2d array)
import numpy as np
#Define random array and sort it
nrows = 10
ncols = 5
a = np.random.randint(nrows, size=(nrows, ncols))
a_sorted = np.sort(a, axis=0)
#Save original order of columns
ori_indices = np.argsort(np.argsort(a, axis=0), axis=0)
#Do some work on sorted array, like e.g row-wise filtering.
#....
#After processing sorted array, move it back to original order:
c=np.array([[i] for i in range(ncols)]).T
a_backsorted = a_sorted[ori_indices, c]
#Check results
print (a); print ()
print (a_backsorted); print ()
print (a_sorted); print ()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The code above calls argsort twice, a evtl. more efficient implementation is in the first answer. For fancy indexing to work, it is important that the c array representing the columns is a list of (single element) lists. That the original indices can be calculated via 2x argsort is a bit of a brain twister, so the first variant (calling argsort only once) is maybe also clearer. (besides faster)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
nrows = 10; ncols = 5
a = np.random.randint(nrows, size=(nrows, ncols))
a_sorted = np.sort(a, axis=0)
a_backsorted = np.zeros_like(a)
c = np.array([[i] for i in range(ncols)]).T
a_backsorted[np.argsort(a, axis=0), c] = a_sorted
```

The reverting of the column-wise sorting is done by inserting the values of the sorted array at the argsorted positions in the backsorted array. Since this is done columnwise, the argsorted positions are paired with the columns represented in the c array